# How can I prove that one algorithm is faster than another in Java

Tags: java, performance-testing

Is there anything in Java that would allow me to take a code snippit and allow me to see exactly how many "ticks" it takes to execute.  I want to prove that an algorithm I wrote is faster than another.

Comment: @William answered you, but this will only measure how fast this implementation of the algorithm is, not much else.

Comment: Minor nitpick: you are not proving that one algorithm is faster than another; rather, you are demonstrating that one implementation is faster than another, for a given set of inputs, on a given machine. The "speed of an algorithm" generally refers to its asymptotic time complexity, not the timing of an execution of a particular implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Ticks"?  No.  I'd recommend that you run them several times each and compare the average results:

```
public class AlgorithmDriver {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int numTries = 1000000;
        long begTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < numTries; ++i) {
            Algorithm.someMethodCall();
        }
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("Total time for %10d tries: %d ms\n", numTries, (endTime-begTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: **DON'T** use average or maximal runtimes! Always use the minimum. Or would you think that if you had `[10, 11, 10, 13, 2000] and [30, 33, 35, 34, 40]` as runtimes the first one wasn't the generally faster one and the one outlier had more to do with scheduling, gc, paging, whatever?

Comment: If I were keeping the data for every single run I'd certainly look at it for other information.  I think this is adequate for a first look.  Median is less sensitive to outliers than average; I think that's a better idea than saying "always use minimum".  Using your head is the best advice.

Comment: Why? The minimum is the minimum amount of time necessary to execute the algorithm. If you run both often enough you should get at least one run without much inference from the OS. Sure, assuming you'll get lots of runs without interference the median will give pretty much the same result as the minimum but that's more by accident. That's all assuming that the runtime of the algorithm for the same inputs won't vary too much, but then that's generally true (if not it gets complicated, but I doubt the median would be that great either in such a case)

Comment: If your argument about "pretty much the same result as the minimum" were correct, then the average would be significant enough.  Your arguments are ridiculous.  I'm not convinced.  I'm sticking with what I know, because you aren't adding to my store of knowledge with this thread.

Comment: Well my first example isn't too far from reality. If while running your algorithm eg GC kicks in you may get large (up to several seconds!) delays. Even if this happens only in 1% of all cases, the average will be extremely skewed, what's so hard to understand about that concept? If "what you know" is that in my above example the second algorithm is more than 10times faster than the first, well good for you, most people and benchmark writers will disagree though.. and really, I thought it was obvious why xX

Comment: @Voo, throw away the largest and the smallest result.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen If you run it often enough you may get more than one outlier. And so far nobody had any reason WHY we should throw away the minimum, all these additional times are only noise after all. Sure you can take the median if you want and it'll result in a quite similar number - just more work since there's often no built-in median() function. And there are problems where "take the minimum" won't work - eg nondeterministic algorithms, but then you need a more complex approach for those anyhow and they're rare.

Answer (score 4):

You probably are asking two different questions:

1. How can you measure the run time of a java implementation (Benchmarking)
2. How can you prove the asymptotic run time of an algorithm

For the first of these I wouldn't use the solutions posted here.  They are mostly not quite right.  Forst, its probably better to use `System.nanoTime` than `System.currentTimeMillis`.  Second, you need to use a try catch block.  Third, take statistic of running times of your code running many times outside of the metric, so that you can have a more complete picture.
Run code that looks vaguely like this many times:

```
long totalTime = 0;
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
try{
   //method to test
} finally {
   totalTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}
```

Getting benchmarking correct is hard.  For example, you must let your code "warmup"" for a few minutes before testing it.  Benchmark early and often, but dont over believe your benchmarks.  Particularly small micro benchmarks almost always lie in one way or another.

The second way to interpret your question is about asymptotic run times.  The truth is this has almost nothing to do with Java, it is general computer science.  Here the question we want to ask is: what curves describe the behavior of the run time of our algorithm in terms of the input size.

The first thing is to understand Big-Oh notation. I'll do my best, but SO doesn't support math notation.  `O(f(n))` denotes a set of algorithms such that in the limit as `n` goes to infinity `f(n)` is within a constant factor of an upper bound on the algorithm run time.  Formally, `T(n)` is in `O(f(n))` iff there exists some constant `n0` and some constant `c` such that for all `n > n0` `c*f(n) >= n`.  Big Omega is the same thing, except for upper bounds, and big Theta `f(n)` just means its both big Oh `f(n)` and big Omega `f(n)`.  This is not two hard.

Well, it gets a little more complicated because we can talk about different kinds of run time, ie "average case", best case, and worst case.  For example, normall quicksort is `O(n^2)` in the worst case, but `O(n log n)` for random lists.

So I skipped over what `T(n)` means.  Basically it is the number of "ticks."  Some machine instructions (like reading from memory) take much longer than others (like adding).  But, so long as they are only a constant factor apart from each other, we can treat them all as the same for the purposes of big Oh, since it will just change the value of `c`.

Proving asymptotic bounds isn't that hard.  For simple structured programming problems you just count

```
public int square(int n){
   int sum = 0
   for(int i = 0, i < n, i++){
     sum += n
   }
   return sum
}
```

In this example we have one instruction each for: initializing sum, initializing i, and returning the value.  The loop happens `n` times and on each time we do a comparison, and addition, and an increment.  So we have `O(square(n)) = O(3 + 3n)` using `n0` of 2 and `c` of 4 we can easily prove this is in `O(n)`. You can always safely simplify big Oh expressions by removing excess constant terms, and by dividing by constant multiples.

When you are faced with a recursive function you have to solve a recurrence relation.  If you have a function like `T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + O(1)` you want to find a closed form solution.  You sometimes have to do this by hand, or with a computer algebra system.  For this example, using forward substitution, we can see the pattern (in an abuse of notation) `T(1) = O(1), T(2) = O(3), T(4) = O(7), T(8) = (15)` this looks alot like `O(2n - 1)`, to prove this is the right value:

```
 T(n) = 2*T(n/2) + 1
 T(n) = 2*(2(n/2) - 1) + 1
 T(n) = 2*(n-1) + 1
 T(n) = 2n - 2 + 1
 T(n) = 2n - 1
```

As we saw earlier you can simplify `O(2n -1)` to `O(n)`

More often though you can use the master theorem which is a mathematical tool for saving you time on this kind of problem.  If you check [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) you can find the master theorem, which if you plug and play the example above you get the same answer.

For more, check out an algorithms text book like Levitin's "The Design & Analysis of Algorithms"

Answer (score 2):

You could use `System.currentTimeMillis()` to get start and end times.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

// your code

long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
System.out.println( "time: " + (end - start) );
```

Comment: This will be useless if the algorithms have already been optimized to produce results in the sub-millisecond range; `(end-start)` will be 0 for such cases.

Comment: Well, if you get 0, that probably means your algorithm is pretty good. Another way would be to check the complexity of the algorithm, (ie nested loops, statements within loops), and see if you can reduce those.

Comment: duffymo's answer would be the next step. Testing multiple times and taking the average.

Comment: For timing algorithms as such you'll want to use `System.nanoTime()`.

Comment: currentTimeMillis() can be quite inaccurate on some systems, ranging from maybe 10-15ms up to whatever so really isn't the best idea for short running algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure wall time with System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime() (which have different characteristics).  This is relatively easy as you just have to print out the differences at the end.

If you need to count specific operations (which is common in algorithms), the easiest is to simply increment a counter when the operations are being done , and then print it when you are done.  `long` is well suited for this.  For multiple operations use multiple counters.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this algorithm efficiency proofs mostly on my Data Structures lesson this year.

First,I measured the time like they mentioned upper.
Then I increased the method's input number with squaring each time(10,100,1000,...)
Lastly,I put the time measurements in an Excel file and drawed graphics for these time values.

By this way,you can check if one algorithm is faster than other or not,slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

- Come up with a few data sets for the current algorithm: a set where it performs well, a set where it performs ok, and a data set where it performs poorly. You want to show that your new algorithm outperforms the current one for each scenario.
- Run and measure the performance of each algorithm multiple times for increasing input sizes of each of the three data sets, then take average, standard deviation etc. Standard deviation will show a crude measure of the consistency of the algorithm performance.
- Finally look at the numbers and decide in your case what is important: which algorithm's performance is more suitable for the type of input you will have most of the time, and how does it degrade when the inputs are not optimal.

Timing the algorithm is not necessarily everything - would memory footprint be important as well? One algorithm might be better computationally but it might create more objects while it runs.. etc. Just trying to point out there is more to consider than purely timing!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use the current time in ms as some of the others have suggested. The methods provided by ThreadMXBeans are more accurate (I dare not say 100% accurate).

They actually measure the cpu time taken by the thread, rather then elapsed system time, which may be skewed due to context switches performed by the underlying OS.

[Java Performance Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447739/java-performance-testing)

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with the Java Framework but i would do it the following way:

1. Define a set of test cases (mostly example data) that can be used for both algorithms
2. Implement a timing method to measure the amount of time that a specific function takes
3. Create a for loop and execute method A (repeatedly, e.g. 1000 times with the whole test data). Measure the timing of the loop, not the sum of the single functions since timing functions can bias your result when called a lot)
4. Do the same for method B
5. Compare your result and choose a winner

Answer (score 0):

If both algorithms have the same definition of a macro-level "tick" (e.g. walking one node in a tree) and your goal is to prove that your algorithm accomplishes its goal in a lower number of those macro-level ticks than the other, then by far the best way is to just instrument each implementation to count those ticks. That approach is ideal because it doesn't reward low-level implementation tricks that can make code execute faster but are not algorithm-related.

If you don't have that luxury, but you are trying to calculate which approach solves the problem using the least amount of CPU resources, contrary to the approaches listed here involving System.currentTimeMillis etc, I would use an external approach: the linux time command would be ideal. You have each program run on the same set of (large) inputs, preferably that take on the order of minutes or hours to process, and just run `time java algo1` vs `time java algo2`.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is compare the performances between two pieces of code, the best way to do is using JMH. You can import via maven and is now official in openjdk 12.

https://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/