# java ternary operator value position on performance?

Tags: java

why `StringUtils.isEmtpy(s)? null:s` is slower than `!StringUtils.isEmtpy(s)? s:null`? in my test, the later one is 1 millisecond faster than first one.

test:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", null, "a"));
    Long start1 = System.nanoTime();
    for (String s : list
    ) {
        String s1 = isEmpty(s) ? null : s;

    }
    Long end1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("null in fisrt: " + (end1 - start1));
    Long start2 = System.nanoTime();
    for (String s : list
    ) {
        String s2 = !isEmpty(s) ? s : null;

    }
    Long end2 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("null in second: " + (end2 - start2));
}
```

//output
    null in fisrt: 98600
    null in second: 8200

Comment: Your testing methodology is flawed. Microbenchmarks are notoriously unreliable.  "Figures often beguile me, particularly when I have the arranging of them myself; in which case the remark attributed to Disraeli would often apply with justice and force: 'There are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics.'" - Mark Twain

Comment: This is not the way to test performance

Comment: @Deadpool,would you please give more details? thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447739/java-performance-testing

Comment: if you want in both for loop just use the same way of `isEmpty()` method still you will see the time difference, which execution is complete depends on JVM loading ,cpu , etc....

Comment: See [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/5221149)

Comment: 1 millisecond diff is not issue, because it depends on your system resource load, jvm-warming and so on. I vote to close this question, because it is off topic, and has nothing with programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Your methodology for calculating performance is flawed as stated in previous comments.

Usage of

```
String s1 = isEmpty(s) ? null : s;
String s2 = !isEmpty(s) ? s : null;
```

has *really **no effect on performance** for any practical list size*. The only overhead between the two LOC is the negation and branching accordingly.

Also, stop worrying of the same. The more you think of micro-optimising, you are almost every time wasting your time because the compiler is smart enough to perform the micro-optimizations itself.

**Moreover hardware is getting cheaper day by day which can run programs unimaginably fast, but maintaining your codebase gets complex with every single line of code.**

Trade your time to make the code more readable for others, IMO, you could have written like

```
String s1 = StringUtils.trimToNull(s);
```

and be done with it.

PS: Please don't compare trimToNull() with your code for performance and worry again!

Answer (score 0):

Running the code as posted on my machine yields :

> null in fisrt: 79347 
>  null in second: 13027

Rearranging the code so "null is second" runs first :

> null in second: 42239
>  null in fisrt: 5526

It clearly shows that you **can't** conclude which is faster from this test.