# most accurate time type in java?

Tags: java, date

I want to compare the performance of certain operations in my application.

Other than using the Date object, is there anything more precise?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503877/how-can-i-measure-time-with-microsecond-precision-in-java

Comment: Are you asking about precision or accuracy? They are not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`public static long nanoTime()` - Returns the current value of the most precise available system timer, in nanoseconds.

As Zach Scrivener [states in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/503937/19679):

> My guess is that since System.[nanoTime](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime())() uses the "most precise
>   available system timer" which apparently only has
>   millisecond-precision on your system, you can't get anything better.

Comment: No, it hasn't only millisecond precision. They access the much more accurate media timer in Java if possible with much more resolution.

Comment: Nano time is not very precise, because it's not updated every nanosecond, like @ThorstenS.mentioned, it has about a millisecond resolution. In my case, using currentTimeMillis() was better choice because nanoTime() had weird "lag spikes".

Answer (score 2):

If you're measuring elapsed time by subtracting two timestamps, you should use `System.nanoTime()` to get those timestamps.  That's what it's for.

Comment: Nano time is not very precise, because it's not updated every nanosecond, like @ThorstenS.mentioned, it has about a millisecond resolution. In my case, using currentTimeMillis() was better choice because nanoTime() had weird "lag spikes".

Answer (score 2):

To get the CPU time you can use the `getCurrentThreadCpuTime` of the Thread Management Bean.
It returns the CPU time used by the actual thread in nanoseconds:

```
    ThreadMXBean threadMX = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    long time = threadMX.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();

    // do something 

    time = threadMX.getCurrentThreadCpuTime() - time;  // CPU time in nanoseconds
```

check the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#getCurrentThreadCpuTime()) for details and some problems like CPU time measurement not being enabled.