# Why are the new pattern matching Switch statements introduced in Java21 slower than regular if-else statements?

Tags: java, java-21

In a simple example, like the one below

```java
long startTime = System.nanoTime();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = scanner.nextLine();
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        
        switch (input) {

            case null -> System.out.println("null");
            case "a", "b" -> System.out.println("a or b");
            case "c" -> System.out.println("c");
            default -> System.out.println("default");
        }
        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1_000_000 + "ms");
```

The output produced is usually:
`Time taken: 28ms`

This is much slower, as if I try to do it with just if-else statements, like this:

```java
 if (input == null) {
            System.out.println("null");
        } else if (input.equals("a") || input.equals("b")) {
            System.out.println("a or b");
        } else if (input.equals("c")) {
            System.out.println("c");
        } else {
            System.out.println("default");
        }
```

`Time taken: 0ms`

I know 20ms doesn't actually matter in practice, but does this make the switch case slower?

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410437/is-stopwatch-benchmarking-acceptable or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447739/java-performance-testing

Comment: Pattern matching is slower than an indexed jump. Don't know why this is considered surprising. It isn't.

Comment: Times obtained with JMH are very similar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mre5.png and by the way, I would not call that *Pattern Matching*, nor does the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.30.2)

Comment: Side note, you’re ignoring the actual advantages of the new Java feature(s). You can write your code as `System.out.println(switch(input) { case null -> "null"; case "a", "b" -> "a or b"; case "c" -> "c"; default -> "default"; });`

Answer (score -1):

I would not use tests that rely on output to the console since io buffering, etc could adversely affect the test.  And the only way to really do this is to use `Java Microbenchmark Harness` or some other reliable testing framework.

But here is how I would do it to get an idea just using `System.nanotime`

- use larger data sets.
- eliminate IO and just focus on method calls of the same type and performance.
- and reverse the order to see how startup time affects the test.

```
Random r = new Random();
String[] arr = r.ints(1000_000, 'a', 'z' + 1).mapToObj(ch -> ch + "")
        .toArray(String[]::new);
int iterations = 100;
System.out.println("Starting");
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        for (String input : arr) {
            if (input == null) {
                foo1();
            } else if (input.equals("a") || input.equals("b")) {
                foo2();
            } else if (input.equals("c")) {
                foo3();
            } else {
                foo4();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println((System.nanoTime()- startTime)/1e9);
}
{

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
   for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        for (String input : arr) {
            switch (input) {
                case null -> foo1();
                case "a", "b" -> foo2();
                case "c" -> foo3();
                default -> foo4();
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1e9);
}
       

 

public static void foo1() {
}

public static void foo2() {
}

public static void foo3() {
}

public static void foo4() {
}
```

Without reversing the order, I get the following:

```
Starting
0.5255654
0.5724467
```

Comment: Instead of reversing the order, independent tests calling only one of the methods should be used. And more than one run. Further, you already did this, but it’s worth spelling out explicitly, not only use larger data sets but also care about taking all branches. Or repeat with different data sets with different likelihoods for the branches, to analyze the impact of the branches taken.

Comment: Which is exactly why something like JMH should be used.